# What is Relative Locator in selenium 4 and what are the types of it?

Tags: selenium, automation, ui-automation

I recently heard about the relative locators in **Selenium 4**. So what exactly it is and what are the types of it?

And secondly how it will help to find element differently than the current locator such as (id,name,tagname,classname,cssselector,xpath,linktext,partiallinktext).

Comment: This question is far too general, and you are asking about a feature that has not been mentioned in any Selenium 4 release notes which is still in alpha version. If you want a better answer, I recommend trying out Selenium 4 for yourself, and coming back when you have a more specific question.

Comment: @Christine : I got the answer please refer this : https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/support/locators/RelativeLocatorTest.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is a new way to find elements based on their location to other elements (above, below , right of , ....)
here is a link to selenium documentation :
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/support/locators/RelativeLocatorTest.java

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a blog post explaining the new methods, how they work, as well as gotchas
http://angiejones.tech/selenium-4-relative-locators/

Comment: Nice Explaination

Comment: So the way it works is that `.toLeftOf()` finds the first element in the DOM where `.getBoundingClientRect().x` is strictly less than the current element's?

Answer (score 2):

main locator is **tagName** and there is different method top on it 
toLeftOf,below,above,toRightOf

to achieve this selenium use getBoundingClientRect() java script function.